# postgress loop issue wehn looping over a table of data

Tags: postgresql, for-loop

Total postgress newbie here. Working with a table that contains multiple rows of data for users for various events. Looking to find the avg of the data for each user for a particular event and then sum up any data above the users avg

This is where I have got to so far using various blogs and forums

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo(
    fanSound INT,
    fanId VARCHAR(80)
);

DO $$
DECLARE
    fan record;
BEGIN
    FOR fan IN
        SELECT DISTINCT phone_id as "fanId", AVG(sound_db) as "avgSound", game_id as "gameId"
        FROM gamedata
        WHERE game_id = '{{gameId}}'
        GROUP BY phone_id, game_id
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO foo SELECT SUM(sound_db) as "fanSound", phone_id as "fanId"
        FROM gamedata
        WHERE game_id = fan.gameId AND phone_id = fan.fanId AND sound_db > fan.avgSound
        GROUP BY phone_id';
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
SELECT * FROM foo
```

getting this error

Error running query: missing FROM-clause entry for table "fan" LINE 3: WHERE game_id = fan.gameId AND phone_id = fan.fanId ... ^ QUERY: INSERT INTO foo SELECT SUM(sound_db) as "fanSound", phone_id as "fanId" FROM gamedata WHERE game_id = fan.gameId AND phone_id = fan.fanId AND sound_db > fan.avgSound GROUP BY phone_id CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 11 at EXECUTE

Can anyone point me in the right direction? From what I can tell I need to push the data into a temp table as the LOOP cant return the results??

If there better ways Im all ears ;)

Comment: Get rid of the unneeded dynamic SQL. But you don't need a loop or PL/pgSQL at all. This can be done with a single `insert .. select ...` statement.

Comment: The immediate issue is `game_id = fan.gameId`. You did not specify the table `fan` in you `FROM`. I'm guessing you wanted `FROM gamedata JOIN fan ON game_id = fan.gameID AND phone_id = fan.fanId ...` Also if the `fan` columns where created as quoted mixed case then you will need to quote them in above.  Also not sure where `{{gameId}}` is coming from?  Not clear what you want the function to do. A `DO` function cannot return results, for that you would need a regular function. In that case you could return the results as a table.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver your reply pushed me in the right direction and I'm underway now.

Probably not as elegant as could be but its a POC type scenario so its working for now

Chur!! (as we say in NZ) ;)

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name your reply pushed me in the right direction and I'm underway now.

Probably not as elegant as could be but its a POC type scenario so its working for now

Chur!! (as we say in NZ) ;)